# How to get the size of the custom gtk widget?

Tags: gtk, gtk3

My gtk_image widget was wrapped in gtkbox, I did all this in anjuta ui builder. I wanted to get the dimensions using the gtk_widget_get_size_request function, but it returned -1. In addition, if the picture is large, it increases the size of the program, so in the first program I wrapped it all in a scroll. Right now I want to make my widget so that the image is scaled depending on the size of the window. For this, I need to know what size of the widget is available for displaying the image. How do i get these sizes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you never set a size request, you will get -1 when getting the size request. I imagine you are actually looking for [gtk_widget_get_allocated_size()](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/Gtk-3.0/classes/Widget.html#Gtk.Widget.get_allocated_size). Also check out [width](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/Gtk-3.0/classes/Widget.html#Gtk.Widget.get_allocated_width) and [height](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/Gtk-3.0/classes/Widget.html#Gtk.Widget.get_allocated_height) allocation. The allocated size is the actual size of the widget, not what the various preferences for the widget are set to.